# TypeError: fetch failed,how can i do

Tags: web3.js

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YtMB.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mZnf.png**strong text**
[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to know how I can fix this one, is it because of my internet problem? Why can't I just connect to the rpc network, I can pick up airdrops.