Error: failed to get recent blockhash: TypeError: fetch failed in Anchor test
I've made simple test script for Anchor running on Devnet.
But it's giving error below:

I found some saying need to change rpc.
But in my end, "connection.getLatestBlockhash()" works fine.
So I think my rpc (https://api.devnet.solana.com/) has no problem.
Here my test script code snippet:
describe("Solana pump fun", () => {
const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
anchor.setProvider(provider);
const owner = (provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet).payer;
const feeInBps = new anchor.BN(100); // 1%
const totalSupply = new anchor.BN(100e9);
const virtualSol = new anchor.BN(100e9);
const targetPoolBalance = new anchor.BN(150e9);
const { platformKeypair } = keypairs;
it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    const platformParams = {
        owner: owner.publicKey,
        feeInBps,
        totalSupply,
        virtualSol,
        targetPoolBalance,
    };


    await program.methods.initialize(platformParams).accounts({platform: platformKeypair, signer: owner.publicKey, }).signers([owner]).rpc();
)}

Thank you in advance!

check out these two question https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/10368/typeerror-fetch-failed-while-trying-to-use-connection-in-web3-js/14285#14285 and https://solana.stackexchange.com/q/13407/1708
